# Slide animation of left floating element vs right floating element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've ran into a inconsistency with the sliding animation in jQuery and I'm not too sure how I can overcome it.

I basically have two floating divs that act as opening and closing doors:

```
.door-one{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('dark-wood.png');
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px black;
}

.door-two{
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('dark-wood.png');
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px black;
}
```

And the animation to govern their movements:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.home-button').click(function(){
        $('.door-one').animate({width: 'toggle'}, 1000);
        $('.door-two').animate({width: 'toggle'}, 1000);
    });
});
```

The problem exists with the left floating element. You see, the right one moves off the page to the right (images and all) in one smooth motion. The left one however just gets 'covered' up and doesn't actually 'slide' off of the page.

Is anyone familiar with this? Is there anyway to get the left element to slide off the page properly?

Comment: Do you have a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background image for right door works, because the float causes it to move right as the door's width shrinks.  The background image simply goes along for the ride.

The background image for the left door does *not* work, because the door doesn't move left when its width shrinks.

An alternative would be to animate the left door's *position* rather than its *width*.

You can do this by removing `float: left` and adding absolute positioning for the left door.  I don't think you can toggle left for this purpose.  But you can animate it in one direction or the other based on its current offset.

**Snippet:**

```js
$('.home-button').click(function(){
  var d1= $('.door-one');
  if(d1.offset().left < 0) {
    d1.animate({left: '0'}, 1000);
  }
  else {
    d1.animate({left: '-50%'}, 1000);
  }
  $('.door-two').animate({width: 'toggle'}, 1000);
});
```

```css
html,body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

.door-one{
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/royal-blue/stackoverflow-4-xxl.png");
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px black;
}

.door-two{
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/royal-blue/stackoverflow-4-xxl.png");
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="home-button">Click me</button>
<hr>
<div class="door-one"></div>
<div class="door-two"></div>
```